# Admob Banner not working on Iive app iOS

Tags: ios, swift, admob

Test ads work both on simulator and device, but not on live app. Happens the same in different 2 apps I tried with.

Any idea of what else can I do?

```
@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let request = GADRequest()

    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    request.testDevices = ["xxx"]
    self.bannerView.adUnitID = "xxx"
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self
    self.bannerView.load(request)
}
```

Comment: please share logs